# How to add pagination to a table in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, pagination

I have this table in the .aspx file and functions in the .cs file to populate the table from the database:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblRoles" runat="server" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="center" Style="margin-top: 1em; margin-left:1.5em; margin-right:1.5em; text-align:center; text-wrap:normal;">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ForeColor="White" BackColor="DodgerBlue" Style="background: #6688FF; height: 4em; text-align: center; text-transform: capitalize;">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="One" Width="5%"/>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Two" width="10%"/>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Three" width="10%"/>
        more here...
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

I was to add pagination to this but would it be possible to do it with `Table` and if so how? All my functions were already written to match the table. For another page I did the pagination with `Gridview` but I would like to avoid changing everything if possible.

Comment: There is nothing in Table that comes pre-defined; You can add `Next` and `Prev` buttons to the table and write your logic of moving data to and fro as per the clicks; It will simple enough to convert this to a `GridView`; You may need to weigh the effort required between both implementations

Comment: why don't you use a `DataGrid or a DataGridView`?

Comment: you can try using a jQuery library like DataTable.js. It can be pretty tricky to get it to work along with your server side code, so best of luck

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well. I got it to work with DataTable.js, but not easily. The DataTable.js library supports not only pagination, but also searching/filtering and sorting of tables. But these are normally HTML tables, not an `<asp:Table>`. In order for it to make HTML tables searchable, sortable, and have pagination, there needs to be `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags. So the same has to stand for an `<asp:Table>`. In order to give an `<asp:Table>` those two tags, you need to set the `TableSection` property to `TableHeader` and `TableBody`:

```
<asp:Table ID="myTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow TableSection="TableHeader">
        <!--A bunch of <asp:TableHeaderCell> tags-->
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow TableSection="TableBody">
        <!--A bunch of <asp:TableCell> tags-->
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow TableSection="TableBody">
        <!--A bunch of <asp:TableCell> tags-->
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Then for support of pagination along with searching and sorting, include these jQuery dependencies in your HTML:

```
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

And finally render your `<asp:Table>` as a DataTable when the document loads (note: jQuery will need referenced!):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#<%=myTable.ClientID%>').DataTable();
}
```